# IPA: How can I pronounce this symbol ⊥⊥ in X⊥⊥Y|Z?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

IPA: How can you pronounce this symbol ⊥⊥ in X⊥⊥Y|Z?

More generally, where can I found the IPA for mathematic symbols?

> [image: ![image]

Comment: As suggeste in the image, read them "independent" and "dependent".

Comment: @GEdgar but, are they have a name? like \nu symbol or \sigma or something else?

Comment: These symbols do not appear in Latex, not even in the `amssymb` package.  I conclude they are not widely used symbols.  There is this symbol $\perp$ obtained using `\perp`.

Comment: @GEdgar In LateX they are \prod and \coprod

Comment: I have never seen `\coprod` used for independence in probability theory.  I have seen `\perp` used for it, however.

Comment: I agree with @GEdgar. These look more like custom made (double) \perp / \bot and \top. \prod and \coprod don’t really fit the context.

Comment: It is in the book `Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning` @GEdgar

Comment: Maybe there is confusion in my question, I want to know the way to pronounce these symbol, not the way to type it in latex. For example, \nu symbol is pronouced as /njuː/

Comment: For who does not know, you can find the way to type any symbol in Latex by using 
http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: That was my first comment.  Pronounce them "independent" and "dependent".

Comment: @GEdgar thank you so much, it sounds crazy to me @@

Answer (score 0):

The first symbol $\prod$ stands for *product*, and the second symbol $\coprod$ for *coproduct*, e.g., in a category.

Comment: The consensus seems to be that these are *not* product/coproduct symbols in this context

Comment: Yes, I know. My answer only refers for the symbols in general. I didn't understand the phrase "how to pronounce" the symbols. I thought of LateX.

Comment: Okay. I believe OP is asking what you would say if you were reading the expression aloud, that is, speaking it.

Comment: I would read aloud "product" and "coproduct", but of course not in all contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as suggested by `b00n heT`
$$
\mathcal X \bot\!\!\bot \mathcal Y \;\vert\; \mathcal Z
\qquad
\mathcal X \top\!\!\top \mathcal Y \;\vert\;\mathcal Z
$$

Note: coded by

`\mathcal X \bot\!\!\bot \mathcal Y \;\vert\; \mathcal Z
\qquad
\mathcal X \top\!\!\top \mathcal Y \;\vert\;\mathcal Z`